# LDAP search all users under baseDN recursively

Tags: node.js, active-directory, ldap

I'm using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/activedirectory2) package to work with active directory. I have AD structure like this:

```
--OU (baseDN)
  --OU (1 lvl)
      --user (CN)
      --user (CN)
      --user (CN)
      --OU (2 lvl)
        --user
        --user
        --OU (3 lvl)
          --user
          --user
          --user
  --OU (1 lvl)
    --user
    --OU (2 lvl)
      ...

--OU
  --OU
    ...
```

I tried this code, but it looks like it searches only inside 1 lvl:

```js
let opts = {
            scope: 'sub',
            filter : '(|(objectClass=person)(objectClass=user))',
            includeMembership : [ 'user', 'group' ], // Optionally can use 'all'
            includeDeleted : false,
            baseDN: 'OU=company,DC=domain,DC=com'
        };

        let ad = new ActiveDirectory(config);
        ad.find(opts, function(err, results) {
           if ((err) || (! results)) {
                console.log('ERROR: ' + err);
                return;
            }
            console.log('Users');            
            let user = results.users.filter(x => x.sAMAccountName == 'myUser'); //nothing
            console.log(user)
        });
```

How can I search recursively through all my baseDN? May be I should use another package?
I use it only on server side and I think I don't need such libraries as [`ldap.js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ldapjs) cause it seems too complicated for my purposes

Comment: The search scope you set in your options, sub, is a subtree search -- a DN and anything under it. That appears to be what you are trying to do. It's possible you are encountering the maximum page size in Active Directory (1,000 records by default but can be configured by AD admins) which restricts the number of records that will be returned in a query.

Comment: tried to set sizelimit to 99999 but didn't help, may be there is a bug in the package, trying to find it out

Comment: Have you set paged to true (http://ldapjs.org/client.html#paging) as well? You'll need to use a size limit less than the max result size set on the directory server.